# Binding data JS

Tags: javascript

I want to bind the data to the {{}} mustache template.

Here the code:

```
<div id="app">
        <h1>An Introduction to {{book}}</h1>
        <div>
            <p>
                {{book}} is a series of fantasy novels written by British author {{author}}.
            </p>

        </div>
    
        <table id="hogwarts">
            <caption>{{school}} Student Table</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{harry.id}}</td>
                <td>{{harry.name}}</td>
                <td>{{harry.gender}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{hermione.id}}</td>
                <td>{{hermione.name}}</td>
                <td>{{hermione.gender}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- DO NOT change anything within <div id="app"> tag -->
    <div>
        The central character in the series is {{harry.name}}, ...
    </div>
```

The script is provided as shown below:

```
<script>
        //data you need
        let data = {
            book: "Harry Potter",
            school: "Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry",
            antagonist: "Lord Voldemort",
            harry: {id: "1", name: "Harry Potter", gender: "M"},
            ron: {id: "2", name: "Ron Weasley", gender: "M"},
            hermione: {id: "3", name: "Hermione Granger", gender: "F"},
            author: "JK Rowling",
        };
        //Implement this bind function
        function bind(data) {
        // write code here
        }
        //invoke the function
        bind(data);
    </script>
```

That is what I'm done so far:

```
function bind(data) {
            
            var template = document.getElementById("app").innerHTML;
            var html = Mustache.render(template,data);
            // console.log(template);
            // console.log(html);
            
            var app = document.querySelector("#app");
        
            app.innerHTML = html; 

            var div = document.querySelectorAll("div")[2].innerHTML; 
            var html2 = Mustache.render(div,data);
            // console.log(div);
            
            document.querySelectorAll("div")[2].innerHTML = html2; 
        }
```

But it doesn't meet the requirement that only allows use pure JS only without the framework ( Im using mustache library)
Anyone help me, thank you

Comment: You could try to look into the Mustache lib and see how they're doing it and port some of their code over. Just my two cents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have any complicated expressions, creating your own template isn't that hard. We can use `String.prototype.replace`, and it will help us go a long way.

```js
const renderTemplate = function(template, data) {
  // use regex to extract {{templates}} and replace the values
  return template.replace(/{{[\w\.]+}}/g, function(s) {
    const expr = s.substring(2, s.length - 2); // remove "{{" and "}}"
    const sections = expr.split(".");
    const val = sections.reduce((prev, cur) => prev[cur], data); // loop through nested object call and access values
    return val; // return the replacement
  });
}
```

We can use it something like:

```js
const data = {
  person: {
    name: "John",
    age: 35
  }
};

const result = renderTemplate("<p>{{person.name}} is {{person.age}} years old.</p>", data);
// ^ "<p>John is 35 years old</p>"
```

Comment: thank you so much. It was a lot of help!

Comment: @BảoVương no problem. I do hope you took something away from this and it'll aid you in your further JavaScript studies. Good luck.